# How to convert pandas dataframe column to string and delete some text of column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert each value in a pandas dataframe column to a string and then delete some text. The values are times. For example, if the value is 11:21, I would like to delete every to the right of the : in every element in the column. 11:21 should be converted to 11.

Comment: That is not the correct way to extract the hour from a datetime column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have following dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': ['09:30:00','09:40:01','09:50:02','10:00:03']
})

df.head()
```

Output:

[image: Output]

If you want to work with time column as a string, following code may be used:

```
df['hour'] = df['time'].apply(lambda time : time.split(':')[0])

df.head()
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Alternatively time can be converted to datetime and hour can be extracted:

```
df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.hour

df.head()
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted. I appreciate it.